# what is difference between partition and replica of a topic in kafka cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

What is difference between partition and replica of a topic in kafka cluster. 
I mean both store the copies of messages in a topic. Then what is the real diffrence?

Answer (score 22):

When you add the message to the topic, you call send(KeyedMessage message) method of the producer API. This means that your message contains key and value. When you create a topic, you specify the number of partitions you want it to have. When you call "send" method for this topic, the data would be sent to only ONE specific partition based on the hash value of your key (by default). Each partition may have a replica, which means that both partitions and its replicas store the same data. The limitation is that both your producer and consumer work only with the main replica and its copies are used only for redundancy.

Refer to the documentation: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi
And a basic training: http://www.slideshare.net/miguno/apache-kafka-08-basic-training-verisign

Answer (score 17):

Topics are partitioned across multiple nodes so a topic can grow beyond the limits of a node. Partitions are replicated for fault tolerance. Replication and leader takeover is one of the biggest difference between Kafka and other brokers/Flume. From the [Apache Kafka site](http://kafka.apache.org/082/introduction.html):

> Each partition has one server which acts as the "leader" and zero or
>   more servers which act as "followers". The leader handles all read and
>   write requests for the partition while the followers passively
>   replicate the leader. If the leader fails, one of the followers will
>   automatically become the new leader. Each server acts as a leader for
>   some of its partitions and a follower for others so load is well
>   balanced within the cluster.

Answer (score 8):

- partition: each topic can be splitted up into partitions for load balancing (you could write into different partitions at the same time) & scalability (the topic can scale up without the instance limitations); within the same partition the records are ordered;
- replica: for fault-tolerant durability mainly;

[Quotes](https://kafka.apache.org/intro):

> The partitions of the log are distributed over the servers in the Kafka cluster with each server handling data and requests for a share of the partitions. Each partition is replicated across a configurable number of servers for fault tolerance.

There is a quite intuitive tutorial to explain some fundamental concepts in Kafka: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_fundamentals.htm

Furthermore, there is a workflow to get you through the confusing jumgle: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_workflow.htm

Answer (score 4):

**Partitions**

A topic consists of a bunch of buckets. Each such bucket is called a partition.

When you want to publish an item, Kafka takes its hash, and appends it into the appropriate bucket.

[image]

**Replication Factor**

This is the number of copies of topic-data you want replicated across the network.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms, partition is used for scalability and replication is for availability.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka topics are divided into a number of partitions. Any record written to a particular topic goes to particular partition. Each record is assigned and identified by an unique offset. Replication is implemented at partition level. The redundant unit of topic partition is called replica. The logic that decides partition for a message is configurable. Partition helps in reading/writing data in parallel by splitting in different partitions spread over multiple brokers. Each replica has one server acting as leader and others as followers. Leader handles the read/write while followers replicate the data. In case leader fails, any one of the followers is elected as the leader.

Hope this explains!

[Further Reading](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2016-11-30-part1-kafka-for-beginners-what-is-apache-kafka.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Partitions** store different data of the same type and

*Yes, you can store the same message in different topic partitions but your consumers need to handle duplicated messages.*

**Replicas** are a copy of these partitions in other servers.

*Your number of replicas will be defined by the number of kafka brokers (servers) of your cluster*

Example:

Let's suppose you have a Kafka cluster of 3 brokers and inside you have a topic with name *AIRPORT_ARRIVALS* that receives messages of Flight information and it has 3 partitions; partition 1 for flight arrivals from airline A, partition 2 from airline B, and partition 3 from airline C. All these messages will be initially written in one broker (leader) and a copy of each message will be stored/replicated to the other 2 Kafka broker (followers). Disclaimer; this example is only for an easier explanation and not an ideal way to define a message key because you could ending up with unbalanced load over specific partitions.

Answer (score -1):

Partitions are the way that Kafka provides **redundancy**.
Kafka keeps more than **one copy** of the same partition across **multiple brokers**.

This redundant copy is called a **Replica**. If a broker fails, Kafka can still serve consumers with the replicas of partitions that failed broker owned